# Setting AUTO_INCREMENT randomly for all new tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to automatically set AUTO_INCREMENT to a random value whenever a new table is created in MySQL?

Some background: as a developer I regularly work with multiple local installs of Moodle.
A few times I have been caught out by subtle bugs in my SQL statements where I've mixed up the IDs from two different tables, but this has been masked by both tables having the same numerical value for their ID. e.g. during development, a forum with ID 1 also has a post in it with ID 1, so an SQL statement which muddles-up forum.id and post.id will appear to work locally, but then start giving errors when deployed to the testing server.

If AUTO_INCREMENT always had a random starting point, then such mistakes would be much more likely to be spotted immediately.

Note - for one Moodle install, it would be trivial to tweak the code to set a random AUTO_INCREMENT value whenever I created a new table. Unfortunately, I currently have 30-40 copies of the Moodle codebase for different clients, with new copies being added frequently, so a solution that worked automatically across all my local databases would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ALTER TABLE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 13125;
```

Which you could probably script it with something like php:

```
<?
  $q = "ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = ".rand(10000,99999);
?>
```

I dont know how much this suits your needs.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Question isn't tagged as `php`, actually. And I'm not sure if OP wants additional constructions to make it work

Comment: I adjusted my edit a bit, I was just trying to suggest a course of action he might want to take.

Comment: As mentioned in the original question, tweaking the PHP code for a single site to set AUTO_INCREMENT during table creation would be trivial. However, having to remember to alter the PHP code for every new site I work on (and not accidentally check it in) is non-trivial, which is why I was looking for a MySQL-level solution.

Comment: Well, you could just create a script which would automatically run after install, and do the job for you. In my personal opinion, this is as close as you can get without changing the code in your application.

Comment: Thanks - I suspected that might be the case, but, was also hoping for something that would happen after table creation, but before the install started adding data. Also, something that would pick up any tables added by plugins (either ones I've installed or ones I've added). This was a bit of a long-shot, just in case someone had a bright idea about how it could be done (I couldn't think of one!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mysqls UUID Feature https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: How could this be used to automatically set the starting values for AUTO_INCREMENT when creating new tables? I'm looking for a solution that does not involve changing the code that is querying the database.